# deeplinking with parameters

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am implementing deep linking in android using intent url. I get a link in mail and when user clicks the link it launches the app if installed else redirects to play store.

Problem is if app is installed and user clicks on link from mail it redirects to play store.This happens frequently. Below is what i have done in my code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

          <data
             android:scheme="content"
             android:host="hostname" />
</intent-filter>
```

**intent url**

```
intent://hostname/#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;package=com.packagename;scheme=content;S.someparameter=ABC12;end;
```

Comment: if possible you can go through branch documentation for deep linking

Comment: my above code is working , but some times it redirects to playstore even if app is installed. I am not getting where i am doing wrong

Comment: Line action=android.intent.action.VIEW; in intent url is unnecessary